# A word for something that is both useful and beautiful

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there a word to describe an object that excels in form and function? I am trying to avoid very general words like *great*, *superb* or *excellent*.

Comment: "It is truly useful since it is beautiful." -- The Little Prince

Comment: @AlbeyAmakiir I love that reference.  Am I correct in thinking it implies that anything that is beautiful is intrinsically useful?

Comment: Is there a reason why you need a single word, and not a phrase? Can you provide more context?

Comment: Can you tell us more about this 'object' of yours?

Comment: @LordScree: I seem to remember some argument, I think from a pop science magazine, that the perception of beauty is an evolved response to usefulness, which makes some sense - that we would be attracted to things that are good for us. Of course, evolution only works in a specific environment, and traits like this can be tricked.

Comment: @AlbeyAmakiir. "All art is quite useless." - *The Picture of Dorian Grey*.

Comment: @LordScree: I believe so. Aside from the evolutionary reason that naught101 mentioned, beauty can have a measurable effect on the mind, which means it can be used to achieve goals. A goal could vaguely be, say, making people feel a sense of wonder, or more specific and obviously useful, like acting as a stress reliever. Not that I expect the science of it was really going through the Prince's mind, but I don't own a copy of the book, so I can't check.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Could it be described as an *[elegant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elegance) solution* or an *engineering [marvel](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/marvel)*?

Comment: *Elegant* could be tough to top; my online thesaurus lists *stylish, graceful,* and *aestetic,* but also *effective, ingenious,* and *inventive.*

Comment: +1 *Elegant* is widespread in math and computing. http://catb.org/jargon/html/E/elegant.html

Answer (score 8):

Something that is *well-designed* is intentionally planned and created so that it is both useful and appealing (sometimes beautiful).

Here are some examples in which it is used:

> [Well-designed logos](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/80-creative-and-well-designed-logos/)
>
> [Well-designed products](http://pinterest.com/soxfords/well-designed-products/)
>
> [Well-designed gardens](http://www.timberpress.com/books/well_designed_mixed_garden/disabato-aust/9780881925593)
>
> [Well-designed websites](http://webdesignfan.com/showcase-of-well-designed-websites/)
>
> [Well-designed rooms](http://www.hgtv.com/decorating/11-steps-to-a-well-designed-room/pictures/index.html)

Comment: Doesn't work for evolved things though - like hands.

Comment: @naught, But it can. As an example, from [an article on pandas:](http://www.mesacc.edu/dept/d10/asb/origins/selection/panda.html) "Their hand is not well designed but it works effectively based on what was available."

Answer (score 7):

The context is unclear, but I suppose the word *something* refers to an actual object.

I'd suggest the adjective "**streamlined**."

It's [defined](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/streamlined) as:

- Designed or arranged to offer the least resistance to fluid flow;
  reduced to essentials
- Having flowing, graceful lines; sleek
- Improved in appearance or efficiency; modernized

For me, this word encompasses beauty in both form and function.

Comment: Seems very centred around engineering of vehicles and doesn't lend itself well to other concepts. My new Gaggia coffee machine is not streamlined.

Comment: Yes, I think so too. But beauty of form and function?

Comment: For me it has to be @cornbread ninja's 'elegant'. Its a word that is also used generically in engineering disciplines. e.g. `elegant design`, `elegant software/code` or `an elegant solution`. Another word, though it suggests something is *well-suited* to its purpose might be 'apt'. Or 'ideal'?

Comment: Well, it depends so much on the context. Why don't you ask the OP to give more?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the adjective "perfect". Not only does it communicate the notion that the object embodies the characteristics of consummate beauty and utility, but that by any other measure or characteristic that is appreciated, the object is...dare I say it, perfect.

Comment: "Perfect" sounds just as general as "great" or "superb." Yes, it does mean "great in every way," but it doesn't specify "form and function."

Answer (score 1):

Gestalt? It is oft used in design circles I believe. It refers to wholeness in design with form and function firmly in mind. The most positive qualities of those individual parts making up the wholeness is presumed. It wouldn't make sense for such a word to refer to the ugly bits making up a wholesome object. One of those aesthetic form qualities could be the adjective beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest calling it the *[acme](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/acme)* ("The top or highest point; pinnacle; culmination") or the *[pinnacle](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pinnacle#English)* ("The highest point"; "An all-time high; a point of greatest achievement or success") of perfection.  Also consider terms like *[standout](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/standout)* ("An exceptional or noteworthy person or thing"), *[superlative](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/superlative)* ("The highest extent or degree of something"; "An adjective used to praise something exceptional"), *[crème de la crème](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cr%C3%A8me_de_la_cr%C3%A8me)* ("Best of the best; something superlative; the very best"), or *[ace](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ace)* ("Used as an exclamation to mean excellent").

Note a problem with some earlier suggestions: the terms *elegant, well-designed, streamlined* are sometimes used of items that have excellent form but fall down on function.  But careful speakers might use the first two of those terms only of items that exhibit excellence in both form and function.

Comment: Having watched Wiley E Coyote get blown up/crunched into an accordion/etc thousands of times as a kid, quality is never the first thing that comes to mind when I see the word "acme".  I doubt many people even know the work has another meaning any longer.

Comment: Even if the terms "elegant, well-designed" do connote items that "fall down on function" (with which I disagree), "acme, standout" and your other examples don't particularly suggest form and function. The OP specifically asked for words that are not general.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer that comes to my mind is the word *nifty*.

Answer (score 0):

I think *neat* could work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Exquisite, polished or "exquisitely polished".

Answer (score 0):

**Amazing, exquisite, marvy, simple, outstanding, fine, neat, inventive**

Answer (score 0):

Ergonomic could possibly be an answer, it is the appropriate word that can help improve your ability to work with the area around you.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. StackExchange seeks to provide *definitive* answers; as such, yours would be improved if you can explain why *ergonomic* is suitable, including a dictionary definition, examples, or links to support its use. Otherwise, it is only a personal opinion. I encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for further guidance.